# ¿Como puedo usar el contenido de una variable que se origino en un foreach, fuera de este mismo en PHP?

Tags: php

mi caso es el siguiente:
Dentro de un foreach descargo el contenido de una consulta mysql y lo asigno a una variable $preferencias (es una serie de números, en este caso 7 y 8 con un echo imprime 78) 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego entonces quiero usar esa variable para ponerla como parte de una condición where de un query (where id_usuario in (7, 8) ). necesito sacar el contenido de la variable $preferencias ¿Cómo puedo sacarlo y separarlos por  comas?, hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente, pero sigo sin poder sacar la variable del foreach para usarla en el query:

```html
foreach($filaCRUD as $fila){
        $preferencia=", ".$fila->por_usuario_id;
        echo "<td><strong>".$preferencia."</strong></td>";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano, gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Agrega todo tu código para poder analizarlo todo y poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba esto

```
foreach($filaCRUD as $fila){
    $preferencia=", ".$fila->por_usuario_id;
    echo "<td><strong>".$preferencia."</strong></td>";
    $tmp[] = $fila->por_usuario_id;
}
echo "prefencia: ".implode(",", $tmp);
```

Saludos!